# Variable not accesable in ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having troubles using a global variable in my ajax response.
LastDate is a variable defined in the page I loaded into my second page. (function load_table)

I am able to acces the variable before the ajax call, but I can't seem to acces it in my ajax succes. because it gives undefined. <==== in code

my code:

```
var dia_date = {};

$(window).load(function()
{    
    DP("eerste keer")
    load_table(); 
} );

function load_table()
{    
    DP('load_table');
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/diagnose_hoofdpagina/table_diagnose/" + DosierID,
            success: function (data) {
                    $("#diagnoses_zelf").html('');
                    $("#diagnoses_zelf").append(data).trigger('create');
                    //initialize_table();
                    update_table(); 
                },
            error: function(){
                alert('error');
              } 
        });
    return false;   
} 



function update_table()
{   
    if(LastDate > Datum)
    {
        alert("LasteDate" + LasteDate);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Datum" + Datum);    
    }

    alert('gast ....  ' + LastDate); // <========== this is promted on the screen so there is no problem
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/refresh_diagnose/" + DosierID,
            dataType: "json",
            data : JSON.stringify(dia_date),
            success: function (data) {
                    var DataDate = new Date(data.Year, data.Month, data.Day, data.Hour, data.Minute, data.Second);
                    alert('lastdate :'+ LastDate + 'date.date   :' + DataDate);

                    //<============ BUT HERE HE GIVES LastDate AS UNDEFINED

                },
            error: function(data){
                alert(data);
              } 
        });  
return false;         
}
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Can annyone help me plaese  ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you set `LastDate`? The difference between your two alerts is that in between (during the ajax request, before the callback) some code could overwrite `LastDate` - otherwise it should work.

Comment: It doesn't get overwritten annywhere. Thats why I don't get it :/

Comment: Then use your debugger and a) watch the variable b) inspect the scope at the point where you get the error that it's undefined.

Answer (score -1):

You can try making a function.

```
var lastDate = #;
function getLastDate(){return lastDate;}

ajax.blablabla.success :{getLastDate();}
```

Comment: `ajax.blablabla.success :{getLastDate();}` should be `ajax.blablabla.success :function(){getLastDate();}`

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, still getting LastDate as undifined